# Code to combine multiple media files using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I am new to ffmpeg

I am trying to combine multiple media files using ffmpeg, I know the ffmpeg concatenation protocol allows this through a command line arguement. I want to know if the C code for this function is available anywhere, so that I can include the same in my program. If not, I would really appreciate if someone could post any suggestions on how to do this. Basically, I want to combine multiple files without doing the decoding and encoding of files.

I tried copying the data from one file to another, while I was able to create a new file, i couldn't play it back.

I searched the ffmpeg library but was unable to locate the code on how the concatenation function works.

Comment: ffmpeg has a concat protocol, demuxer, and filter. Each of these is used for different purposes, but you didn't specify which you're interested in. See [How can I join video files?](http://ffmpeg.org/faq.html#How-can-I-join-video-files_003f) for short descriptions of each and links to further information.

Comment: Thanks, I am interested in the concat protocol, sorry if my post was not clear earlier.